# Best way to extend group functionality

Tags: extension, groups

I have a requirement to extend change add/edit screen of static group and add some extra fields there, like default email subject.

For saving extra fields I'm thinking about adding a new table, linked to groups table.

Then to display those fields I will need to create my own version of CRM_Group_Form_Edit.

Now I'm thinking what is better way to do all this, 2 options:

- put required classes and templates in custom folder and change them. Looks like this is standard way.
- instead of editing CRM_Group_Form_Edit I could create my own class then
  change CRM_Group_StateMachine to point to that class which would extend
  CRM_Group_Form_Edit

2nd option kind of sounds a better way thinking about feature upgrades.

are there same case scenarios when to use what? or any other suggestions for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you cannot use a custom set that extends groups? This allows you to add various fields to civicrm_group which appear in the add/edit screen of all groups

You can select "Groups" in the "Used For" selection here:

http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/custom/group?action=add&reset=1

Comment: looks like there is no reason not to use it :) I'm too new to know all functionality